# 7-Zip: How can I test all zips within a hierarchy from the command line

Tags: 7-zip

I have a system where my files are stored in ISOs and extracted into a folder which has a hierarchy, but I would like to know if the files have extracted properly, by testing them. I have tried "T" in the command line and it seems to do the entire hierarchy of a specified folder, but I just want to confirm, please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do from command line, but 7zip has an easy to use wrapper DLL for C#, "SevenZipSharp", which allows you to create archives or unpack them. And in the same program you could test the content of the folders in which you unpacked the data. Let me know if you need code samples.

Comment: Thank you, Tobias, but that's too elaborate and beyond me for what I wanted. It seems I was right about my above statement, that all I need to do is use the "T" parameter with a specified folder with 7-Zip, and it will test everything within that folder.